# Espresso & network calls (firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso

I've just started getting in to UI testing with espresso. I've written a simple test which attempts to test if a user is registered correctly. It currently looks like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class RegisterTest {

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<RegisterActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(RegisterActivity.class);


@Before
public void runThisBefore(){

}


@Test
public void registerUserCorrect(){
    onView(withId(R.id.etUsername)).perform(typeText("ESPRESSOTEST"));
    onView(withId(R.id.etPassword)).perform(typeText("ESPRESSOTEST"));
    onView(withId(R.id.etConfirmPassword)).perform(typeText("ESPRESSOTEST"));
    onView(withId(R.id.etEmail)).perform(typeText("ESPRESSOTEST@gmail.com"));
    closeSoftKeyboard();
    onView(withId(R.id.etConfirmEmail)).perform(typeText("ESPRESSOTEST@gmail.com"));
    closeSoftKeyboard();
    onView(withId(R.id.etAge)).perform(typeText("25"));
    closeSoftKeyboard();
    onView(withId(R.id.rbMale)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.bRegister)).perform(click());
    onView(allOf(withId(android.R.id.button1), withText("Ok"), isDisplayed())).perform(click());

}


@After
public void checkLogin(){
    //delete user;

}
}
```

After alertDialog button is clicked...

```
final Firebase registerUser = new Firebase(FirebaseReference.FIREBASE_URL);

                registerUser.createUser(userEmail, userPassword, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>(){

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {


                    registerUser.authWithPassword(userEmail, userPassword, new Firebase.AuthResultHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAuthenticated(AuthData authData) {
                            Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); //create new hashmap
                            userMap.put(FirebaseReference.KEY_PROVIDER, authData.getProvider()); //authentication method
                            userMap.put(FirebaseReference.KEY_USER_NAME, userName); //set username
                            userMap.put(FirebaseReference.KEY_EMAIL, authData.getProviderData().get(FirebaseReference.KEY_EMAIL)); //user email
                            userMap.put(FirebaseReference.KEY_AGE, userAge);
                            userMap.put(FirebaseReference.KEY_SEX, userSex);
                            //create timestamp (purpose is for easy user comparison later on)
                            long createTime = new Date().getTime();
                            userMap.put(FirebaseReference.KEY_TIMESTAMP, String.valueOf(createTime));

                            //set the map to a new node in the users child
                            registerUser.child(FirebaseReference.CHILD_USERS).child(authData.getUid()).setValue(userMap);

                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAuthenticationError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "An error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    showErrorMessageToUser(firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Once the register button is clicked, `createUser()` is called on my firebase reference and it waits on one of two callback methods. Either `onSuccess()` or `onError()`. However, with espresso, as soon as the register button is clicked, the test ends and no network activity even occurs. Is there a way for the test to wait and then check which callback method is triggered?

Comment: What is happened after `onView(withId(R.id.bRegister)).perform(click());onView(withId(R.id.bRegister)).perform(click());` - you're showing dialog, launching intent like open new activity, or what? The answer depends on what would be done after clicking register button

Comment: I've updated my question. After the register button is clicked, an alertdialog is shown to the user for him/her to confirm their user details. Upon clicking "Ok", createUser() is ran.